# uploading two files with different location using flask

Tags: python, flask

I tried to upload two files woth two different location but when uploading files, I'm getting this error "ValueError: View function did not return a response". I tried everything to get it works but no luck.

html code:

```
<form action="/NewCases/" method=post class="form-horizontal">
<h2>Add New Cases: </h2>
<div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
      <input type="text" id="casename" name="casename" class="form-control"
        placeholder="Enter Case Name:" required>
</div>
<div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
      <input type="text" id="adminname" name="adminname" class="form-control"
        placeholder="Enter Case Name:" value="{{ current_user.username }}">
</div>
<div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
      <input type="file" id="imagefile" name="imagefile" class="form-control"
        placeholder="Enter Hard Disk File:" required>
</div>
<div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
      <input type="file" id="memimagefile" name="memimagefile" class="form-control"
        placeholder="Enter Memory File:" required>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Signup</button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

flask code

```
@app.route('/NewCases/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def NewCase():
    try:
        if request.method == 'GET':
            return render_template('admin.html', DICT=DICT)

        if request.method == 'POST':
            idtest = str(uuid.uuid4())
            idtestfilter = idtest.replace('-','')

            adname= request.form['adminname']
            casen = request.form['casename']
            imagefile = request.files['imagefile']
            memimagefile =request.files['memimagefile']



      if imagefile > 0:
              imagefilename = secure_filename(imagefile.filename)
              file.save(os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER , imagefilename))
              return redirect(url_for('index'))
      if memimagefile > 0:
              imagefilename = secure_filename(memimagefile.filename)
              file.save(os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER , memimagefile))
              return redirect(url_for('index'))

      c, conn = connection()
            c.execute("INSERT INTO cases(id,casename, adminname, imagepath, memimagepath) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                        (thwart(idtestfilter),thwart(adname),thwart(casen),thwart(imagefilename),thwart(memfilename)))
            conn.commit()
            flash("case inserted!")
            c.close()
            conn.close()



            flash('Cases successfully added')
            return redirect(url_for('EditCase'))
    except Exception as e:
        error = e
```

Please help me out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to point out is that your Python code is failing, but you are catching and ignoring *all* exceptions (well, almost all). The main reason that your Python code is failing is because a bad request is being received. You would know that if you did not catch and ignore all exceptions. At least print a message, and `raise` the exception again.

Anyway, you are uploading files so you need to set the encoding type for your HTML form to `multipart/form-data`, like this:

```
<form action="http://127.0.0.1:5000/" method=post enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
```

That's the cause of the bad request.

I assume that you have imported all required modules and functions such as `uuid`, `secure_filename` etc., however, you are not quite saving the files properly. Use `imagefile.save()` and `memimagefile.save()`, not `file.save()`.

Also, because both files can be uploaded at the same time, and because there is database code that should be run, you should not `return` after saving the files.

Finally, your code assumes that the form fields will always be present in the form. If one is missing your code will fail with a `KeyError`.